# Router (Synology) translates external IP address to internal

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, synology, ddns

My previous CISCO router (from my ISP) has been changed to Bridged mode, because I wanted to use mine (**Synology**). Afterwards the internet connection and the subnet worked fine, but my (DDNS) FQDN (from NO-IP.com) got resolved wrongly:

Desired scenario (also on the subnet)

- the FQDN gets resolved to an external IP address **every time** instead 88.1.2.3 of the internal 192.168.1.x
- Port Forwarding: from 9900 to internal 192.168.1.100:80, from 9990 to internal 192.168.1.101:80

Current state:

- if I try to reach the FQDN from the subnet it gets resolved to an internal one 192.168.1.x
- both the request to myfqdn.ddns.net:9900 AND the request myfqdn.ddns.net:9990 gets routed to 192.168.1.100:80

Trials:

- I experimented with several DNS settings on the router (without deep understanding), it did not get better.
- I tried to reach my servers (NAS) from outside, it works like a charm.

Remarks: one of the devices defined in the Port Triggering rules is a QNAP NAS, which had a UPnP activated at the beginning (now turned off); at that time there has been such mysteries.

Answer (score 1):

Synology Router does not have a NAT Loopback feature, which would use the WAN IP of the router. That's why the domain name gets resolved to the internal IP.

Workaround: set up and configure your own DNS Server.